# How can I retrieve an item when I press the "E" key into inventory in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm new to Unity, I'm working on my first game and I'm trying to allow players to take an item with an "E" on the keyboard so that the item can be put into inventory. So far, it's only done through TriggerEnter, it works, but somehow I can't put it on "E". I will be happy for any advice.

here is the script

```
public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour

{

public GameObject inventory;
public GameObject slotHolder;
public GameObject itemManager;
private bool inventoryEnabled;

private int slots;
private Transform[] slot;

public GameObject itemPickedUp;
private bool itemAdded;
private bool pickUpAllowed;


public void Start()
{
    //slots being detected
    inventoryEnabled = true;
    slots = slotHolder.transform.childCount;
    slot = new Transform[slots];
    DetectInventorySlots();
}
public void Update()
{
    if (pickUpAllowed && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
    {
        AddItem(itemPickedUp);
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.I))
    {
        inventoryEnabled = !inventoryEnabled;
    }

    if (inventoryEnabled)
    {
        inventory.GetComponent<Canvas>().enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        inventory.GetComponent<Canvas>().enabled = false;
    }
}

public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.tag=="Item")
    {
        print("Colliding!");
        itemPickedUp = other.gameObject;
        AddItem(itemPickedUp);
        pickUpAllowed = true;
    }
}

public void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    if (other.tag == "Item")
    {
        itemAdded = false;
        pickUpAllowed = false;
    }
}

public void AddItem(GameObject item)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < slots; i++)
    {
        if (slot[i].GetComponent<Slot>().empty && itemAdded==false)
        {
            slot[i].GetComponent<Slot>().item = itemPickedUp;
            slot[i].GetComponent<Slot>().itemIcon = itemPickedUp.GetComponent<Item>().icon;

            item.transform.parent = itemManager.transform;
            item.transform.position = itemManager.transform.position;

            if (item.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>())
                item.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = false;

            Destroy(item.GetComponent<Rigidbody>());           

            itemAdded = true;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the current script, `AddItem()` is called in the `OnTriggerEnter()` method. This will set `itemAdded` to `true` (in the `AddItem()` call). When `E` is pressed, `AddItem` will be called again, nothing will happen in the for-loop because of the `if (slot[i].GetComponent<Slot>().empty && itemAdded==false)` check.

I would try removing the `AddItem()` call from the `OnTriggerEnter()` method.

Comment: it works, but I have to stand in that object, could it be set, if I focus on it, will I take it? (If so, how?) Otherwise, thank you

Comment: Ahh, I would try using [Physics.Raycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) to raycast from the direction/location of the camera. If it hits an item, then you know that you can take it.

Comment: Somehow the raycast doesn't work for me, I tried it, but somehow it doesn't work very well, here's the code [link](https://ctrlv.cz/nLxi)